# how to fetch the value of a multiline column in sharepoint in a variable using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a multiline column named `COL`.I want to fetch its value in a variable using javascript.
 I used the following syntax:

```
var res=$('input[title="COL"]').text();
```

but the result is undefined . Please help!!

Comment: `named COL` .. named? or is that the `title` ? you also may want to show the HTML involved

Comment: Well, it would be better if we could see the html code.

Comment: <tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<H3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Add Comments</nobr>
</H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="comment">
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff16{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="col" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff16',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@col')}" />
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff16description{$Pos}" FieldName="col" ControlMode="New" /></td>
</tr>

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("*[fieldname='col']");`

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
var res= $('nobr:contains("COL")').closest('tr').find('.ms-rtestate-write').html();
```

Or

```
var res= $('nobr:contains("COL")').closest('tr').find('input[id$="$TextField_spSave"]').val();
```

Comment: var res= $('nobr:contains("COL")').closest('tr').find('input[id$="$TextField_spSave"]').val();  this gives an undefined value

Comment: var res= $('nobr:contains("COL")').closest('tr').find('.ms-rtestate-write').html();   res here stores <p/> <br/>

Comment: By default, this field will store HTML code, if you only want to get the text. we can use : $('nobr:contains("COL")').closest('tr').find('.ms-rtestate-write').text();